# Open file dialog in js/jq

Tags: jquery

I'd expect the following to open file dialog, but it doesn't. Why?

```
$('<input type="file"/>').click();
```

Comment: How did you create the input file??

Comment: $('<input type="file"/>')

creates file input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider that hazardous if my browser popped up system dialogs unrequested. Just a thought that it's probably a security restriction. *I certainly could be wrong in this case.*

Comment: One can make your browser pop up file dialog in an non obvious way. Using this plugin for instance: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ocupload

Comment: @artemave, as far as I can tell, that plugin still requires a click in order to popup the dialog.

Comment: Yeah, but this click may not be meant to open file dialog at all. Anyway, your answer makes sense and definitely postponed a bit the inevitable brain failure I am doomed to end up with being a web developer.

Answer (score 6):

It's not (shouldn't be) possible to programmatically open file dialogs. [The standards say so](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361).

I said shouldn't as IE6 allows this, AFAIK.